# Can I somehow take a table valued parameter and return it as a IQueryable<int>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Basicly if I could do

```
db.ExecuteTableValueQuery(ids)
   .Join(db.Set<MyEntity>(), id => id, e => e.Id, (id, e) => e);
```

I then could execute a performant table value query and also benefit from the standard `IQueryable` API and join in my standard entities.

I know that `db.Database.SqlQuery` works with table value parameters, but it return `DbRawSqlQuery<T>` which is not compatible with `IQueryable`

Is this solvable somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is under investigation in EF Core

I just added my 2 cents to the discussion over at github

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13239#issuecomment-532553529